# The definite and zero article with the word "civilization"

Tags: articles, definite-article

Tell me please why *the* is not used in the first following sentence and is used in the second one.

> Ancient egyptian civilization existed for a long time.
>
> The Inca civilization flourished for a long time.

Is *the* omitted because of the word *ancient*, or the use of *the* is optional in both sentences?

Comment: The reason seems to be that you have written the sentences this way. Are they quoted from somewhere? Can you provide some context? Can you think of a difference between "The Inca civilization" and "Egyptian civilizations" that can explain the choice of articles?

Comment: civilization is like wealth, happiness and poverty. No article required. If you write: "The Inca civilization", it can be because you are comparing it to "The Mayan one".

Comment: **ancient** is the specifier there.  We also say *ancient history is...* not *The ancient history is...*

Comment: Laugh:  The first sentence is from Crash Course World History. The second one is given by the Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say

> Ancient Egyptian civilization flourished for centuries.

the specifier is "ancient" and "Egyptian" is a modifier.  We're not talking about modern Egypt but ancient Egypt and its civilization.

We could do the same with Inca:

> Inca civilization flourished for a long time.

Which civilization?  Inca civilization.

If we use the definite article:

> The Inca civilization flourished ...

we're referring to the *aforementioned* civilization of the Incas.  Most likely the sentence was culled from a paragraph about Inca civilization.